# How to simply remove a page numbering from table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, tocloft

I have a list of tables, list of images and list of abbreviations that i added to the toc.
[image]

But i dont need the number of those pages to be shown in the toc. Unfortunately i tried the most of many solutions from Stackoverflow and other pages without success.

The code look like this:

```
documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\tocloftpagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[footnote]{acronym}

\clearpage
{
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \newpage
  \tableofcontents

  \newpage
  \clearpage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
  \listoffigures
  \newpage

  \newpage
  \clearpage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
  \listoftables
  \newpage

  \newpage
  \clearpage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
  \input{folder/abkuezungen/abkuerzungen}
  \newpage 

\clearpage
}
```

Is there any simple solution to fix these particular problem?

Comment: `tocloft` also `\cftaddtitleline{〈file〉}{〈kind〉}{〈title〉}{〈page〉}`. You could thus try `\cftaddtitleline{toc}{section}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}{}` instead of `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}`

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you. Can you add it as an Answer please?

Comment: Unrelated: you should remove the group (those `{` and `}` you've surrounded your toc and lists of stuff with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `tocloft`'s

```
\cftaddtitleline{〈file〉}{〈kind〉}{〈title〉}{〈page〉}
```

instead of

```
\addcontentsline{〈file〉}{〈kind〉}{〈title〉}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\tocloftpagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[footnote]{acronym}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

  \cftaddtitleline{toc}{section}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}{}
  \listoffigures

  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
  \listoftables

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that (a) employs the [tocbibind](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocbibind) package to simplify the inclusion of the LoF and LoT in the ToC and (b) modifies the behavior of `\addcontentsline` locally to suppress the display of the associated page numbers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\tocloftpagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[footnote]{acronym}

% new instructions:
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % don't show an entry for the ToC in the ToC...
\usepackage{etoolbox}          % for '\patchcmd' macro

\begin{document}
\let\origaddcontentsline\addcontentsline % save the original form of \addcontentsline
\patchcmd{\addcontentsline}{\thepage}{}{}{} % suppress display of page number

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
%\newpage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
%\input{folder/abkuezungen/abkuerzungen} % don't have access to 'abkuerzungen.tex'
\newpage

\let\addcontentsline\origaddcontentsline % restore original form of \addcontentsline

\section{Remainder of document}
\end{document}
```